# Calling C# from C++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

I have been looking for a way to call a function written in a C# EXE project (VS 2008) from a C++ DLL project. I can include the C# code as part of the C++ project itself if that is possible. All that I have been able to find is calling the C# DLL from C++.

Ultimately I want to call C# code from VB6 but I ask the question this way because I don't believe the later way is possible without an intermediate step.

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Ultimately I want to call C# code from VB6 but I ask the question this way because I don't believe the later way is possible without an intermediate step.

You can register the C# classes to be visible to COM, and then call them directly from C++ or VB6.

For details, see the [Example COM Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20.aspx) on MSDN, as well as [Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173184.aspx).

Comment: @mydogisbox For calling from VB6, this is by far the easiest option...  For using from C++, C++/CLI is easier - but if the only purpose is to use in VB, this isn't really hideous

Comment: Thanks, but what I would prefer to do is wrap the C# code so it is callable by VB later on. It doesn't have to be C++, I just want everything in a DLL. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: @IanReynolds That's what the COM visible stuff does - it makes your assembly (DLL) directly usable by VB6 (and C++, and anything else that can use COM).  This is the only way to have your C# code usable as a *single DLL* - wrapping in C++ would cause you to have 2 DLLs (the C# + the wrapper)

Comment: I apologize for my inexperience. Currently, the C# code doesn't assemble as a DLL. The C# builds an executable.

Comment: @IanReynolds You can use COM still, but typically, if you want to "wrap" it, you'd make the C# code a library.  YOu can have a separate C# project make an executable that uses the library, as well as the VB side.

Comment: @ReedCopsey I don't disagree that this is the best way to do it, but anything involving both vb6 and COM is ugly IMO.

Comment: It wouldn't be too big of a chore to change the C# code into a library, right? Even though the C# code is quite long. The thing is, the C# code that I am dealing with is automatically generated so manually making quite a few changes to it would be very time consuming.

Comment: @IanReynolds It should just be a matter of changing the project type to make it a library.  If it's autogenerated, change the generator :)

Answer (score 1):

You can compile your c++ project with the /CLR option and then call C# from within it. To do that you need to include vcclr.h and then add a using statement for each dll you need to call from.

```
#include <vcclr.h>
#using <System.dll>
```

Comment: To avoid having to recompile your entire project with /clr, you could also develop just an assembly/DLL, written in C++/CLI that exposes an unmanaged interface to your C# code